# Help understanding N＋でいる+ N

Tags: grammar

This is the the full sentence below:

> A: メールで経歴などはお知らせいただきましたが、今日はさくひんはお持ちですか。
>   B: はい、もってまいりました。ご覧いただけますでしょうか。
>   まだ勉強不足ですが、**専門家でいらっしゃる先生**にいろいろアドバイスいただければと思っております。

The book I was reading was teaching that the でいらっしゃる is acting like ている in a respectful form。But I never heard that we can use N＋でいる+ N before...

Is 専門家でいる先生 equals to 専門家の先生 or 専門家先生？

Comment: Do you know anything about である?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know why the "books" Japanese-learners use often give you incorrect information.

We do ***not*** say 「専門家{せんもんか}で**いる**先生{せんせい}」; We say 「専門家で**ある**先生」.

The honorific form of that is 「専門家で**あられる**先生」.  So, in meaning,

> 「専門家でいらっしゃる先生」＝「専門家であられる先生」＝「専門家である先生」

In these phrases, 「先生」 means "you", the listener.

> "***You, the specialist***"

「専門家**の**先生」 is fine, but 「専門家先生」 is not.  That 「の」, needless to say, is ***appositive***.  The appositive 「の」 has been explained numerous times on SE.

Comment: Do you mean that 専門家でいらっしゃる先生 too is wrong?

Comment: No, of course not.   Just read the first highlighted line.  I would NOT have used the equation sign if 専門家でいらっしゃる先生 were incorrect.

Comment: Oh, I seem to have missed that line completely then.

Comment: I say 「専門家でいる先生」, but it might not be appropriate Japanese.

Comment: Somehow it seems as if this has gone off-focus and missed addressing the OP's original purpose of understanding N+でいる+N.  I was drawn to this thread because I also came across examples of this pattern (ご機嫌でいるために) and was looking for an explanation